# How to read the selected value of a dropdown for use in a second dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working on a side bar for a google sheet.  I have a html page.  The data that i am sending it is in two parts.  I have accounts and each account has properties.

```
{
      "name": "accountSummaries/223471136",
      "account": "accounts/223471136",
      "displayName": "G4MeasurmentTesting",
      "propertySummaries": [
        {
          "property": "properties/307799514",
          "displayName": "Ga4CsharpTesting",
          "propertyType": "PROPERTY_TYPE_ORDINARY",
          "parent": "accounts/223471136"
        }
      ]
    },
```

What i want to do is display two drop downs in my menu the first being accounts, the second being the properties under the account.

My issue is how do i reload the second select when the user selects the first one?

I have given the first select a name `<select id="account" name="account">` then try to load the data for the second one using that `accounts[account.selected].propertySummaries.length;`

Its not working as i am seeing `ReferenceError: account is not defined` which implies to me that its not seeing the name of the select.

There must be a way to detect which item was selected in the first select right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <? var accounts = listAccounts();      ?>    
    <? const item = accounts[1];?> 
    
<label>Account: </label>
<select id="account" name="account">
  <option></option>
    <?  for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= i ?>"><?= accounts[i].displayName ?></option>
    <? } ?>  
</select>
    
<!-- Not working  -->
<label>property: </label>
<select id="view" name="view">
  <option></option>
    <?  for (var i = 0; i < accounts[account.selected].propertySummaries.length; i++) { ?>
        <option><?= accounts[account.selected].propertySummaries[i].displayName ?></option>
    <? } ?>  
</select>    
<!-- Not working  -->

   <?= accounts ?> <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code is giving an error  `ReferenceError: account is not defined`

## code.gs

```
function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

   // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('GA Menu')
      .addItem('Alert Test', 'ShowMessage')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
      .addItem('Second item', 'ShowPrompt'))      
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')    
      .addToUi();

  
}

// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs?hl=en#code.gs_1

function showSidebar() {

 var html = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate(); 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .showSidebar(html);
}
```

It does work if I force it by specifying say 0 so the issue is not with it being able to read my data.   So its not an issue with the data form at the issue is with linking the two selects.

```
<label>property: </label>
<select id="view" name="view">
    <?  for (var i = 0; i < accounts[0].propertySummaries.length; i++) { ?>
        <option><?= accounts[0].propertySummaries[i].displayName ?></option>
    <? } ?>  
</select>
```

## update attempt 2

Another idea was to try to grab it using document

```
<? const account = document.getElementById('account'); ?>
```

Which didnt work either it just gave me

> ReferenceError: document is not definedDetails

Comment: Your code is referencing `account.selected` but I'm not seeing `account` defined anywhere, just like the error says.

Comment: <select id="account" name="account">  <---  its the name of the select drop down i am trying to detect selected from.    I have edited my question to be more clear what I have tried to do to solve this issue.

Comment: You are only showing templated scriptlets which are run when the page is initially loaded.  Where is your `<script>` to show the event handler `document.getElementById("account").addEventListener("change", myFunction)`?  And also show your server function that shows the sidebar where the template is filled in.

Comment: @TheWizEd see now we are getting some where.  I don't have that.  i did try document.getElementById you can see it in the second update but shows an error as well.   added code.gs check edit please

Comment: How is `accounts` defined in your template?  And `<?= accounts[i].displayName ?>` requires something like `html.accounts = accounts;` in your `showSidebar` before you `evaluate`.  Give me a little time and I will make a moke up of what I would do.

Comment: You are a star thanks!  I was starting to think this wasn't possible.

Comment: Now, I noticed that the discussions have already been advanced. I apologize that I posted an answer without noticing the discussions. If my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your answer as well. As you can see im learning.  Your answer contains serval things i didn't even know was possible.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you got something from the answer, I'm glad.

Comment: @Tanaike I hope we have a chance to meet at a GDE conference some time.

Comment: Yes. Me too! And, I appreciate that I'm always studying from your content. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In order to set the values to the second dropdown list by the 1st dropdown list, JavaScript is used.

  - In your HTML, the second dropdown list is created using JavaScript with the value of the first dropdown list.
- When the HTML template of Google Apps Script is used, when the calculation is run with `evaluate()` method, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f1436d88423077115d2c249862f12f17)
- In the case of HTML template, when the HTML is loaded, the HTML created by `evaluate()` is put as static. So, `account` in your HTML cannot be used. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification? I think that in this case, there are several approaches.

#### Modified script:

##### HTML side: `Page.html`

```html
<label>Account: </label>
<select id="account" name="account" onchange="sample(this)"><?!= firstOptions ?></select>

<label>property: </label>
<select id="view" name="view"><?!= secondOptions ?></select>

<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

<script>    
const accounts = JSON.parse(<?= accounts ?>);

function sample(e) {
  const select = document.getElementById("view");
  select.length = 0;
  const { propertySummaries } = accounts[e.value];
  propertySummaries.forEach(({ displayName }, i) => {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = displayName;
    option.value = i;
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
}
</script>
```

- By loading the values of `accounts`, after the HTML was loaded, this value can be used.

##### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```js
function showSidebar() {
  const accounts = listAccounts();
  const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page');
  html.accounts = JSON.stringify(accounts);
  html.firstOptions = accounts.map(({ displayName }, i) => `<option value="${i}">${displayName}</option>`).join("");
  html.secondOptions = accounts[0].propertySummaries.map(({ displayName }, i) => `<option value="${i}">${displayName}</option>`).join("");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html.evaluate());
}
```

- In this case, it supposes that `listAccounts()` returns the values like below.

  ```
    [{
        "name": "accountSummaries/223471136",
        "account": "accounts/223471136",
        "displayName": "G4MeasurmentTesting",
        "propertySummaries": [
          {
            "property": "properties/307799514",
            "displayName": "Ga4CsharpTesting",
            "propertyType": "PROPERTY_TYPE_ORDINARY",
            "parent": "accounts/223471136"
          }
        ]
      },
      ,
      ,
      ,
    ]
  ```
- When `showSidebar()` is run, you can see the 1st dropdown list. When you change the 1st dropdown list, the 2nd dropdown list is changed.
- UPDATED: I noticed that when the sidebar is opened for the 1st time, the initial value of the 2nd dropdown list is not set, while the initial value of the 1st dropdown list is the 1st element. For this, I updated the script. If you are not required to set the initial value to the 2nd dropdown list, please use the previous version.

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script for explaining the result. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

### Added:

In the case of `Should I / can I place my listAccounts method in the page.html file along with the sample method you showed.`, when your `listAccounts()` doesn't include the methods of Google Apps Script, you can use the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

##### HTML side: `Page.html`

```html
<label>Account: </label>
<select id="account" name="account" onchange="sample(this)"></select>

<label>property: </label>
<select id="view" name="view"></select>

<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

<script>

// Please set your value here.
function listAccounts() {
  return [{
      "name": "accountSummaries/223471136",
      "account": "accounts/223471136",
      "displayName": "G4MeasurmentTesting",
      "propertySummaries": [
        {
          "property": "properties/307799514",
          "displayName": "Ga4CsharpTesting",
          "propertyType": "PROPERTY_TYPE_ORDINARY",
          "parent": "accounts/223471136"
        }
      ]
    },
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ];
}

const accounts = listAccounts();

function sample(e) {
  const select = document.getElementById("view");
  select.length = 0;
  const {propertySummaries} = accounts[e.value];
  propertySummaries.forEach(({displayName}, i) => {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = displayName;
    option.value = i;
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
}

// When HTML is opened, this function is run. And, the initial values are put to the 1st and 2nd dropdown list.
function init() {
  accounts.forEach(({displayName}, i) => {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = displayName;
    option.value = i;
    account.appendChild(option);
  });
  accounts[0].propertySummaries.forEach(({displayName}, i) => {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = displayName;
    option.value = i;
    view.appendChild(option);
  });
}

init();
</script>
```

- In this case, if the methods of Google Apps Script are included in `listAccounts()`, this script cannot be used. Because Google Apps Script cannot be run with the client browser. Please be careful about this.

##### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```js
function showSidebar() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

- In this case, on the Google Apps Script side, only the sidebar is opened.

Comment: It worked like a charm.   I have a question.   Should I / can I place my listAccounts method in the page.html file along with the sample method you showed.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Exactly!  I tried to add it but missed that it had to be declared with in the HTML file.

Comment: Is there any difference performance wise having everything in the html file?  Development wise it feels neater to me having everything in one place.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for replying. When the HTML template is used, the process cost of `evaluate()` is added. And also, when the calculation like the for loop is run with `evaluate()`, the process cost becomes high. When `google.script.run` is used, the process cost also becomes high. But, if a value is required to be dynamically sent and get with the Google Apps Script side, this method is required to be used. In your situation, when you can achieve your goal in HTML without Google Apps Script, I think that when all scripts are included in an HTML file, the process cost will become the lowest.

Answer (score 2):

I see @Tanaike has beaten me to an answer but as promised I'm providing a mock up of how to do it through Templated HTML as well as through using google.script.run.

First the server side code in Code.gs.  I use `listAccounts()` both in the template and in the client side `<script>`.

Then I show how I would modify the html code to include the event handler.

**Code.gs**

```
function showTest() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test");
  html.accounts = listAccounts();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(),"Test");
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

// Mock up data
function listAccounts() {
  let accounts = [ {account: 11111, displayName: "name11111", propertySummaries: [ {displayName: "prop11111"}, {displayName: "prop11112"} ]}, 
                    {account: 22222, displayName: "name22222", propertySummaries: [ {displayName: "prop22222"}, {displayName: "prop22223"} ]},
                    {account: 33333, displayName: "name33333", propertySummaries: [ {displayName: "prop33333"}, {displayName: "prop33334"} ]}];
  return accounts;
}
```

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <label>Account: </label>
    <select id="account" name="account">
      <?  for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= i ?>"><?= accounts[i].displayName ?></option>
      <? } ?>  
    </select>
    
    <label>property: </label>
    <select id="view" name="view">
    </select>    

    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
    <script>
      var accounts = null;
      function accountOnChange() {
        let i = document.getElementById("account").selectedIndex;
        let account = accounts[i];
        let select = document.getElementById("view");
        let options = select.options;
        for( i=options.length; i>0; i-- ) {
          options.remove(i-1);
        }
        account.propertySummaries.forEach( property => {
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = property.displayName;
            select.options.add(option);
          }
        );

      }
      (function() {
        try {
          document.getElementById("account").addEventListener("change",accountOnChange);
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
            function(value) {
              accounts = value;
              let select = document.getElementById("view");
              accounts[0].propertySummaries.forEach( property => {
                  let option = document.createElement("option");
                  option.text = property.displayName;
                  select.options.add(option);
                }
              );
            }
          ).listAccounts();
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```